# Jenkins check if env.BRANCH that starts with a letter (v) followed by a number (v1) is greater than 1

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm expecting something like `branch = "v1"` or greater than 1, like v2 or v3.

I need to be able to do something like:

```
if branch == "v2" or greater than 2
do stuff
```

branches can also be `master`, `feature/something`, `v1`, etc. which shouldn't meet the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
String getVersion = env.BRANCH_NAME
def getBranchTag = getVersion.substring(1)

if ( "$getBranchTag" > 1) {
  do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to be able to dynamically account for the possibility of "v3", "v4", "v5", etc.

Comment: Hi @aphexlog I have updated my answer. if you print the ```getBranchTag```it will only give you the number after starting ```v``` so you can use it according to your requirment

Comment: Will this also treat "master", "main", "feature/blah", etc. the same as if it were "v1"?

Comment: @aphexlog well you just asked about if it's greater than v1 etc so I gave you the logic but for master etc you have to add some other if conditions to check

Comment: those details are toward the bottom of my original post. The issue there is that i dont want to expect exact values in the additional if conditions, because i won't know what they are. Just needed to account for branch = "vN" where N = some number, and should only meet the if condition if that second character (N) is greater than 1. all other pattens should not match the if

Comment: meybe something like `if ( getVersion.startsWith('v') && "$getBranchTag" > 1) ?

Comment: What happens at `v9 / v10` ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the solution was simply:

```
String thisVersion = "v2".replace("v", ""); // e.g v2
String otherVersion = "v1".replace("v", ""); // e.g v1

def versionLaterThan(x) { x.toInteger() > 1}

println("thisVersion: " + versionLaterThan(thisVersion));
println("otherVersion: " + versionLaterThan(otherVersion));
```

outputs:

```
thisVersion: true
otherVersion: false
```

The I can make a conditional to run if `thisVersion` is true